# ¿Por que no puedo loguearme en una sesion luego de encriptar la contraseña?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Muchas gracias por dedicar tiempo y esfuerzo en ayudar a resolver este problema.

Lo que ocurre es que tengo tengo un pequeño sistema web que hace de panel de control de usuarios.
Esta hecho con *PHP*, *BOOTSTRAP*, *JQUERY*, *MYSQL*

El problema es que cuando hago el login, encripto la contraseña de la cuenta antes de registrarlo en sistema.
Luego cuando deseo loguear con esa cuenta la contraseña la encripto y la comparo con la base de datos, pero por alguna razon no son iguales. Hasta donde lo que se que la incriptacion de una cadena es siempre la misma. En mi caso uso md5.

Les dejo el extracto del cogido para que se entienda mejor:

```
REGISTRO:
$db = new Conexion();
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);



$sql = $db->query("SELECT nombre FROM Coordinador WHERE nombre='$nombres' 
                  OR email='$correo' OR rut='$rut' OR pass='$pass' LIMIT 1;");


if($db->rows($sql) == 0) { 

  $db->query("INSERT INTO Coordinador (rut, dv, nombre, apellidop, apellidom, direccion, 
                          ciudad, email,image_perfil, estado, pass)

              VALUES      ('$rut','$dv','$nombres','$apellidop','$apellidom','$direccion',
                          '$ciudad','$correo','$image_perfil','Activo', '$pass');");
```

---

```
LOGIN:

$db = new Conexion();
  $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

  $sql = $db->query("SELECT id FROM Coordinador WHERE (nombre = '$data'
                    OR email='$data') AND pass='$pass' LIMIT 1;");
```

PASS ENCRIPTADA DE LA BD = `81dc9bdb52d04dc20036`

PASS ENCRIPTADA INGRESADA EN EL LOGIN = `81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055`

Nuevamente agradezo por su tiempo y dedicacion. Saludos

Comment: ¡Hola! Primero verifica que te está devolviendo en ambos casos, es decir imprime el valor de `$_POST['pass']` en ambos casos (`var_dump($_POST['pass']);` justo después de la linea `$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);`) a ver que te devuelven. Puede que esté tomando dos valores distintos.

Comment: @Carlo Echeverría de cuanto es la longitud máxima permitida de donde guardas las passwords encriptadas en tu db? si no me equivoco es eso.

Comment: Muchas Gracias a ambos por su disposicion. Efectivamente era la longitud del campo de la base de datos. Que descuido jaja
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes un pequeño problema en la DB en la columna donde estás almacenando las contraseñas encriptadas, cambia del máximo de 20 a 32 (El cual es el número de caracteres que retorna la función md5).